# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS wifi not working

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, realtek, realtek-wireless

Initially, when I installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion x360 for 2-3 hrs everything worked fine but now suddenly my wifi is not working.

Kernel version: 6.5

Network card: Realtek 8822be

Ubuntu version: 22.04.3 LTS

when i use `lshw -class network`this is the output

```
description: Wireless interfaceproduct: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adaptervendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.physical id: 0bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0logical name: wlo1version: ffserial: c0:b5:d7:df:cd:53width: 32 bitsclock: 66MHzcapabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wirelessconfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11resources: irq:155 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1200000-a120ffff
```

Before I also tried Linux Mint same issue was there.

---

**Update**: when I restart my laptop wifi connects for 1 min then disconnect again

The error it was showing is:

```
Activation of network connection failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch from kernel 6.5 to 6.2.