# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Wi-Fi randomly drops every few minutes

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I have a custom built PC that I chose to put Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on. It's been running great up until a few days ago. My motherboard has Wi-Fi built-in and I noticed it would just randomly drop. Reset my router and everything and it was still happening, but I got a USB Wi-Fi adapter because I thought it was the card in the board itself but the issue started happening with the USB adapter too. I wanted to go ahead and just take a software update error approach before assuming it's a hardware fault.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: enp12s0
       version: 05
       serial: 04:7c:16:d9:30:69
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:39 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc50ffff memory:fc510000-fc513fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:41:0e:e4:84:23
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=____000000-20221227123243 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:104 memory:fc20300000-fc203fffff memory:fc400000-fc407fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@2:5.4
       logical name: wlx9418655dc484
       serial: 94:18:65:5d:c4:84
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921u driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.2.164 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I didn't immediately see anything when I did a `journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` either.

Edit: I forgot to do sudo and now for some reason the network has stopped randomly dropping. Very weird.

Edit2: After running `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` I am getting an output which has warnings.

```
Jan 17 15:51:34 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528294.1320] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="c35dc574-7111-4322-8651-550e452d176f" name="RAGtrey 1" pid=4087 uid=1000 result="success"
Jan 17 15:51:34 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528294.1321] device (wlp13s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 15:51:34 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528294.1322] device (wlp13s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 15:51:34 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528294.1323] device (wlp13s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'RAGtrey 1' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 17 15:51:34 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528294.1323] device (wlp13s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 15:51:39 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <warn>  [1705528299.6840] device (wlp13s0): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Jan 17 15:51:39 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528299.6841] device (wlp13s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 15:51:39 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <warn>  [1705528299.6843] device (wlp13s0): Activation: failed for connection 'RAGtrey 1'
Jan 17 15:51:39 trey-MS-7D78 NetworkManager[1626]: <info>  [1705528299.6844] device (wlp13s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
~
```

Comment: Did you do `sudo journalctl ...`? It won't tell you as `$USER`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator I feel like a bit of a goober now. Forgot sudo. Now it seems to not want to drop the network too. This is very strange.

Comment: @waltinator Okay, to sort of respond now. It did drop again. added the `sudo journalctl ...` information this time as my second post edit.

Comment: Still truncated. If we can't see the whole message, we cannot help.

Comment: @waltinator I copied and pasted it straight from the command so that is very strange.

Comment: What is your processor? I have a suspicion that it has to do with AMD power saving.

Comment: @oldtechaa Sorry for the delayed response. I have a Ryzen 7 7700X. I think it was a kernel issue though because it isn't happening on the later kernel of Pop OS. I am also running a NVIDIA GPU. So I don't know if there is anything else it could be.

Comment: If it is AMD power saving, what can be done about this?

Comment: I'm testing the mt7921e.disable_aspm boot flag and will let you know the progress. The situation looks good so far for use with that flag. That said, it really should be fixed so that the PCIe link can be deactivated properly, and I'm inclined to believe that one specific kernel commit between 6.4 and 6.5 is responsible for this. It's not an Ubuntu-exclusive issue as I've compiled my own custom upstream git kernels and it still happens.

Comment: I don't think it's AMD-specific either, because another similar question asker had an Intel processor.

Comment: @oldtechaa That is interesting stuff. I was experiencing like a little soft crash yesterday. But it seems to be completely fine after a restart on Pop. Even then it wouldn't completely shut my connection out. I don't think overclocking would do anything for the processor either. I still stand firm that the issue is entirely kernel related. Hopefully Ubuntu takes note of this.

Comment: For comparison sake, Pop OS is on 6.6.10 kernel and the issue isn't as bad in that one.

Comment: Yes, I am noticing extraordinary variations between kernel configurations and versions. I have compiled dozens of different kernels and tested them with a rather large variation in the frequency of failures. I am pretty sure that it doesn't happen at all in a 6.4 kernel. I suspect this commit included in the 6.5 kernel: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt7921?id=525c469e5de9bf7e53574396196e80fc716ac9eb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubuntu 22.04 - wifi freeze after hwe kernel upgrade to 6.5 (was fine on 6.2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499938/kubuntu-22-04-wifi-freeze-after-hwe-kernel-upgrade-to-6-5-was-fine-on-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found another answer page ([Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS wifi not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500342/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-wifi-not-working)) with another person having trouble with getting Wi-Fi working by switching to the 6.2 kernel. It so far seems to be working. It is disappointing that Ubuntu completely broke my Wi-Fi card with the 6.5 kernel.